# Git pull to overwrite conflict files only

Tags: git, github

I am trying to set up a process that will automatically pull from the repo every a few minutes and set up some script to run and make local changes.

For example, I have two changed files in the local working directory, one file has a new commit from the remote server, and another one does not.

```
fileName1.txt (no conflict)
fileName2.txt (has conflict)
```

then, when I try to `git pull`, there will be conflict because of the conflict for `fileName2.txt`.

What I am trying to solve is,

1. keep `fileName1.txt` as it is;
2. overwrite `fileName2.txt`

Then, Manually, I can do,

```
git checkout fileName2.txt
git pull
```

In this case, I have to specify the fileName that I want to checkout. How to automatically find the conflict files and `checkout` them?

I can not use

```
git reset --hard && git pull
```

or

```
git checkout . && git pull
```

because these will overwrite both `fileName1.txt` and `fileName2.txt`, how to only overwrite the file that has conflict??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do want to do? to pull changes and keep only the server side code in case of conflict?

Comment: @CodeWizard, Hi, I would like to pull the files that have conflicts from the server and local files, but only these files, not the ones that have local change but no conflict to pull. Thx

Comment: git cannot checkout different versions of files into same working copy. If you checkout a version you checkout all of it. So probably what you want in not possible.

Comment: @max630, Fair Enough. Thank you, then I have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`

to get a list of only the files with conflicts. You can use this list with your original solution (git checkout) to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think this will do the trick. I tried in the command line. but not showing any result.